# numpy.histogram return values aren't the same size

Tags: python, numpy

Why does the `numpy.histogram` return values of `hist` and `bin_edges` not have the same size? Instead `bin_edges` has `(length(hist)+1)`. This becomes an issue when attempting a best fit line for the histogram because then the two operates have different sizes. What can I do to make the two match? Do I just trim off the last value from `bin_edges`? Which value from `bin_edges` doesn't correspond to its respective `hist` value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I ask you to count the number of people in a room by age ranges, you might tell me:

- 10-17 years: one person
- 18-29 years: three people
- 30-50 years: two people

That's three bins but four edges (10, 18, 30, 50 in the way NumPy reports edges).

If you want to convert those four edges to three values which somehow identify the bins, you could:

- Use the lower value to represent each range (i.e. discard the last edge returned by NumPy).
- Use the upper value.
- Use the midpoint of each range.
- Use the mean, median or mode of each group's values.

It's up to you, NumPy isn't making this choice for you.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on using the midpoint of the range? Suppose I have a set of values which has size 13000. What will be the appropriate steps in using the midpoint of the range?

Comment: Use `(max + min) / 2` where max and min are values in a particular bin.